# How to rewrite code into one using javascript and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have two methods like below.

```
 const handleRowClick = React.useMemo(() =>
     !isRunning
         ? (itemId: string) => {
             startRun({items: [itemId] });
         }
         : undefined,
     [startRun]
 );

  const handleSelectedItemsClick = React.useMemo(() =>
      !isRunning
          ? (items: string[]) => startRun({ items: items })
          : undefined,
          startRun]
  );

  handleRowClick(itemId);
  handleSelectedItemsClick(itemIds);
```

as seen from above `handleRowClick` takes a string as an argument whereas handleSelectedItemsClick takes an array of strings as an argument.

how can I rewrite the above methods into one such that it can handle either a string or array of strings as input?

could someone help me with this? thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `useCallback()` if you're memo-ising functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at function param set the the type `string | string[]`

the inside a function

`(itemId: string | string[]) => {startRun({items: Array.isArray(itemId)?itemId:[itemId] });}`

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleSelectedItemsClick = React.useMemo(() =>
    !isRunning
    ? (items: string[]) => startRun({ items: items })
    : undefined,
    [startRun]
);

const handleRowClick = (itemId) => {
    handleSelectedItemsClick([itemId]);
}

handleRowClick(itemId);
handleSelectedItemsClick(itemIds);
```